# Java maps with a key of length and value of number of occurences

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a large text file that I have processed into individual words (called tokens in my program). I need to take those tokens and add them to a map which has a key of the length of the word and a value of the number of occurences. For example a list of (hi, to, say) would give (2:2,3:1). ignoring the key of 1 or any other keys as there are no cases of them.

Would something like:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> tokenSizes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>;

public void processToken(String token)
{
    Integer value = tokenSizes.get(token);

    tokenSizes.put(token.length(), (value == null) ? 1 : value + 1);    
}
```

work?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, you are trying to get the key that matches the token String, which is the original word, and is not what you want. You first want to get the length of the String token and and if it exists as a key in the `Map`, get the stored count value for that key and update the count. If it doesn't exist yet in the map, then you want to store the length as a key and the value as 1 (first time count).

Here is an example program that does just that:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TokenSizes {

    Map<Integer, Integer> tokenSizes = new HashMap<>();

    public void processToken(String token){
        Integer len = token.length();
        if(tokenSizes.containsKey(len)){
            tokenSizes.put(len, tokenSizes.get(len) + 1);
        }
        else{
            tokenSizes.put(len, 1);
        }
    }

    public void printTokenSizes(){
        System.out.println("Token Sizes:\n" + tokenSizes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TokenSizes ts = new TokenSizes();
        ts.processToken("hi");
        ts.processToken("to");
        ts.processToken("say");

        ts.printTokenSizes();
    }
}
```

Which generates the output:

> Token Sizes:
>
> {2=2, 3=1}

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements,

```
public void processToken(String token)
{
    Integer value = tokenSizes.get(token.length());

    tokenSizes.put(token.length(), (value == null) ? 1 : value + 1);    
}
```